# Why does this SetInterval code work for making Ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajax.net, javascript

**I have this code:**

```
setInterval(sendAjax('search', 'q'), 100 * 10);
```

Which I thought would work to execute my function sendAjax(param,param) every 1 second.

However, this is not the case. It only executed the function once.

Does anyone know why this occurs and any solutions?

Regards, 
Taylor

Comment: try `setInterval(function(){sendAjax('search', 'q');}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do the following:

```
setInterval("sendAjax('search', 'q')", 100 * 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're using setInterval() right.

Usually it is used like:

```
setInterval("aFunction()", 100 * 10);
```

The reason why your script is invoking once is because the interpreter evaluates sendAjax('search', 'q') once. This is the only invocation that it makes.

Check out this link under setInterval():

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So why wouldnt this work?

function refreshAjax()
  
{   

sendAjax('search', 'q');  
 
}   

setInterval("refreshAjax", 100 * 10);

Comment: You forgot the brace '()' as in : setInterval("refreshAjax()", 100 * 10); Hope that cleared it up :)